# XUnit conditional tests

Tags: xunit

I am writing some xunit test to validated the correctness of an xml document, some of the xml elements are optional so I would like to write an xunit test that will run only if the optional element is present

I have an xml builder class that creates the document and inserts the optional elements if they are present in the dto.

Comment: It's not the unit testing framework's responsibility to decide whether it should run or not, however it's up to you what assertions do you have in your test case. You could simply return from the test case if the attribute is not present and perform the assertion if it is present.

Comment: Thanks, do you mind putting this as an answer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not the unit testing framework's responsibility to decide whether it should run or not, however it's up to you what assertions do you have in your test case. You could simply return from the test case if the attribute is not present and perform the assertion if it is present.